# adding week numbers to Dojo calendar

Tags: javascript, jsp, datepicker, calendar, dojo

Dojo offers two kinds of widgets to display a datepicker with a textbox. There is the Calendar widget: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/widget/Calendar.html
and there is a DateTextBox https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/DateTextBox.html#dijit-form-datetextbox

I would like to show the ISO week number in this dialog. The ideal situation is a column on the left of the datepicker indicating the week number for that row. Is it possible to extend these widgets like that?

Some examples http://jsfiddle.net/pMD3S/9/ show the current date in the footer of the datepicker. Maybe the format of this can be changed? I haven't found the property for it in the documentation.

```
<body class="claro">
    <input 
        id="dateBox"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox"
    />
</body>
```

I'm open for suggestions on this. The (easy) option to show the week number in the date format in the actual textbox is not an option. I need to help users making the selection, not verifying if their choice was correct.

Comment: I think the only way is to extend the DateTextBox widget into your own widget. Learn how the original widget works internally and try with code overrides and extentions to add this function yourself.

Comment: In matrix view they are showing the week number. Try manipulating that and you might find what you need.

Comment: sorry, what is `ISO week`?